# Can not use front audio output in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, audio-jack

Hello good morning I have a problem that I am unable to solve. I have been looking for some possible solution but I have not clarified much. My problem is as follows, the computer tower I have has two audio outputs on the rear and the front on the rear works without problem but the front I have been unable to make it work. Then I hit all the information that I think can serve and thank you in advance in case anyone can guide me to solve the problem.

The output of the command: lspci | grep Audio

```
00: 1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series / C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller Chipset (rev 05)
01: 00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD / ATI] Cape Verde / Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
```

In Alsamixer I can see the following information:

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: IDT 92HD89E2
```

And in alsamixer too, in the system information:

```
/ Proc / asound / cards
0 [PCH]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7f10000 irq 31

/ Proc / asound / devices
Sequencer
2: [1]: control
3: [1- 3]: digital audio playback
4: [1-7]: digital audio playback
5: [1-8]: digital audio playback
6: [1- 9]: digital audio playback
7: [1-10]: digital audio playback
8: [1-11]: digital audio playback
9: [1- 0]: hardware dependent
10: [0]: control
11: [0- 0]: digital audio playback
12: [0- 0]: digital audio capture
13: [0- 1]: digital audio playback
14: [0- 2]: digital audio capture
15: [0-0]: hardware dependent
33: timer

/ Proc / asound / pcm
00-00: 92HD89E2 Analog: 92HD89E2 Analog: playback 1: capture 1
00-01: 92HD89E2 Digital: 92HD89E2 Digital: playback 1
00-02: 92HD89E2 Alt Analog: 92HD89E2 Alt Analog: capture 1
```

As for the different controls that I get in the Alsamixer there are the following:

```
<Master> PCM Front Surround Center LFE Side Line Line Boo Line Boo Mic Boos Mic Boos S / PDIF S / PDIF D Beep Capture Capture Digital Input So Input So Loopback
```

The output of the command: aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK hardware devices ****
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD89E2 Analog [92HD89E2 Analog]
Sub devices: 1/1
Subdevice # 0: subdevice # 0
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: 92HD89E2 Digital [92HD89E2 Digital]
Sub devices: 1/1
Subdevice # 0: subdevice # 0
Card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Sub devices: 1/1
Subdevice # 0: subdevice # 0
Card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Sub devices: 1/1
Subdevice # 0: subdevice # 0
Card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Sub devices: 1/1
Subdevice # 0: subdevice # 0
Card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Sub devices: 1/1
Subdevice # 0: subdevice # 0
Card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
Sub devices: 1/1
Subdevice # 0: subdevice # 0
Card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
Sub devices: 1/1
Subdevice # 0: subdevice # 0
```

The output of the command: pacmd list

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24510792/

Comment: I don't want to be rude but giving about 800 lines to read is not very practical. First some elementary questions. Did you check whether the front connector is connected to the motherboard? If yes, has the front connector ever worked? If yes, what did you connect to the front connector to verify it is working or not? Depending on what tool you have installed, Open Sound Settings -> Output tab or Volume Control -> Output Devices. You should see Built-in Audio: Speakers. Is the volume slider all the way to the left (silence)? 
When you plugin

Comment: a headset in the front connector, does Speakers change to Head phones?

Comment: And I did not want to be ungrateful at all. I wrote the commands that the users had requested in similar cases, and I thought that they could be useful. I apologize if I exceeded, I just wanted to make things easier.
Answers:
- The front connector is connected to the board. I've tested  the headphones on the bios and in windows too and there is no problem
In Ubuntu I have never worked
The system configuration shows the analog audio output, but only the rear speakers. It's not muted
When I connect the headphones there is no change. The sound keeps coming out through the speakers
Thank you

Comment: No offense taken, mate. I understand your frustration with the issue. 
Let us ascertain that the insertion of the jack is noticed by the hardware. Open the Sound Settings GUI (start `pavucontrol`). Look at Built-in Audio Analog Stereo. Do you see port: Speakers and does it change to Headphone when you connect them to the front?

Comment: Thank you very much. I start pavucontrol with music playing through the speakers, and when I connect the headphones, nothing appears, nor is there any change. The loudspeakers are still ringing.

Comment: If you don't see anything change then the motherboard will not switch the audio.  I think it is save to say you have a hardware problem. I advise you to check the cable connector on the motherboard. Is it connected in the right position. Perhaps you have a manual for the motherboard with pictures how the connectors must be positioned. Perhaps there is a BIOS setting?

Comment: It can not be a hardware problem because in the BIOS there is a function to check the components of the computer and there is no problem when testing them. And if I boot with Windows, they work, too.

Comment: The BIOS checks the audio cards and there are 2 in your system. See the pacmd list outout you sent; line 610. (`pacmd list-cards` will show just the cards). Index 0 is the HDMI card, index 1 the Alsa Card (line 675). Lines 721-732 shows the ports it has. What I miss there is the Properties for analog-output. I will put the output of my system for reference.

Comment: It seems like the audio driver does not report well to the system.

Comment: I ran thought a very similar problem involving that same intel hda sound driver, and here was my solution:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/943200/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-can-i-use-the-integrated-intel-alc268-audio-device-or-wh/944220#944220

Answer (score 0):

Below the (output of `pacmd list-cards`, clipped for the part of my sound card.

```
index: 3
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 9
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e10000 irq 34"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "8c20"
    device.product.name = "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#2: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#3: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#4: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
ports:
    analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:

    analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:

    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24534777/

Comment: output of my `pacmd list-cards`

Comment: Yes, lines 119-123 show strange behavior, they show `available: unknown` and `device.icon_name = ...` is absent. Very strange. Please have a look at: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1121805 about reinstalling the audio driver. I hope that helps.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24536170/

Comment: My pacmd list-cards after reinstalling the audio driver, I think it's the same

Comment: I agree. I am out of ideas now  :-(

Comment: Oh.. an idea popped up. What is the output when you boot a Live USB ?

Comment: This is what will work for you:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/943200/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-can-i-use-the-integrated-intel-alc268-audio-device-or-wh/944220#944220